# Get value from database from the same table depending on dropdownlList selection value in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: json, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to show Istanbul card id in select list and show the information associated with this id in input html
But it does not work

'this is page Test.cshtml'

```
 @model Transportation.Vm.`VmIstanbul`
    
    @section Scrypt{
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    }
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Customer/Test",
                    data: "{}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Card id</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            s += '<option value="' + data[i].Balance + '">' + data[i].IstanbulCardId + '</option>';
                        }
                        $("#departmentsDropdown").html(s);
                    }
                });
            });
    
            function getValue() {
                var myVal = $("#departmentsDropdown").val();
                $("#show").val(myVal);
            }
    
        </script>
    </div>
    <form id="myForm" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Test">
        <label for="departmentsDropdown"><b>Card</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" onchange="getValue()" id="departmentsDropdown" name="departmentsDropdown"></select><br />
        <input type="text" value="" id="show" />
    </form>
```

this is  the Customer Controller

public IActionResult Test()
{

```
    var data = from als in ctx.TbIstanbulCards select new { als.IstanbulCardId, als.Balance };
    return Json(data.ToList(), System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  
}
```

this is  the VM Class

```
 public class VmIstanbul : TbIstanbulCard
    {

        public double TransportNumber { get; set; }
        public double NumberOfStops { get; set; }
        public string Vehicles { get; set; }
        public double AvailableBalance { get; set; }
        public double DeductedAmount { get; set; }

    }
```

This is  Class of Istanbul Card model

```
public partial class TbIstanbulCard
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IstanbulCardId { get; set; }
        public decimal? Balance { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual TbCustomer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it sounds like you are trying to change values in a select element and want the html input elements to change when you do this. Is that right? Either way, you have 1 of 2 options. The solution will either be implemented with JS or with a controller action. With the controller action, the page will need to refresh.

Comment: could you help me please and solve it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,If you use asp.net core,no need use `System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`,otherwise,it will get 500 error when post back.

Secondly,you could use `console.log(data)` in success function to check the post back data,the format of these data should be Camel Case(`data[i].balance` and `data[i].istanbulCardId`).

At last,you need put all your js in `@section Scripts{}`.

Here is a whole working demo:

View:

```
@model VmIstanbul

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Customer/Test",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Card id</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        s += '<option value="' + data[i].balance + '">' + data[i].istanbulCardId + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("#departmentsDropdown").html(s);
                }
            });
        });

        function getValue() {
            var myVal = $("#departmentsDropdown").val();
            $("#show").val(myVal);
        }

    </script>
}
<form id="myForm" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Test">
    <label for="departmentsDropdown"><b>Card</b></label>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="getValue()" id="departmentsDropdown" name="departmentsDropdown"></select><br />
    <input type="text" value="" id="show" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{

    var data = from als in ctx.TbIstanbulCards select new { als.IstanbulCardId, als.Balance };
    return Json(data.ToList());

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it works as you said but I got this result why it doesn't get me my form HTML . its displayed as an array without form

Comment: like that 
[{"istanbulCardId":70421190,"balance":111},{"istanbulCardId":86129851,"balance":4354},{"istanbulCardId":393853914,"balance":756},{"istanbulCardId":510124891,"balance":657},{"istanbulCardId":709243545,"balance":8898},{"istanbulCardId":1512774818,"balance":654},{"istanbulCardId":1696897042,"balance":654},{"istanbulCardId":1915069818,"balance":888888},{"istanbulCardId":1930244033,"balance":56},{"istanbulCardId":2087443244,"balance":234}]

Comment: Hi @ALAAELDIN,Did you mean you still have problems?Could you share what is your error message?

Comment: Hi @Rena  i wanted to share with you the problem as a video but I didn't know how to upload it so could you click on (here is my problem ) and see it please I made it as gif photo like you   ![here is my problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wKXbTCTnsCLsbBRjoT9N9QZaKmKGlE2/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hi @ALAAELDIN,I have no access to your gif photo.

Comment: Hi @Rena   Could you try again I've given you access please?        ![here is my problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wKXbTCTnsCLsbBRjoT9N9QZaKmKGlE2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ok.I got your issue now.That is because your Test.cshtml will get into the `Customer/Test`.Your view need to get into the method like:`public IActionResult Test(){return View();}` to return a view.Then your ajax in your view need change a request url and change the request method like:`public IActionResult AjaxTest()
{

    var data = from als in ctx.TbIstanbulCards select new { als.IstanbulCardId, als.Balance };
    return Json(data.ToList());

}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel frustrated with this problem that took me more than 10 days. I hope that you will help me in solving this problem. I have uploaded the entire project to the drive and shared it with you and you can solve the problem any way you want, and I thank you in advance for helping me ..    ![Here Is My Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IRy-UsaGzF5bZJu1tjKAyGSxZP7TkaML/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @Rena I want to thank you so much for helping me all this time. The problem has already been resolved as you suggested